# Memory Management in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, memory

So, I have a navigation controller, which is connected to a view controller. From that view controller you can go to a the same type view controller but with different content. The view controllers are memory intense, so it's quiet expensive to push each new one of them. The problem is that when I click the back button and view controller gets popped, the memory doesn't release itself. Is there something I should do, like set thing that I don't use to nil etc. ? Because, suppose that I have 5 images to display, each of them takes 5-10 mb in memory, when I push a new view controller on top of the one I was on I spend 30-50mbs of memory, and that is okay, but when I click the "Back" button and the view controller gets popped up, I expect these 50mbs to be released. That is not the case, however. Can somebody give me a hint on what should I do to manage this memory more efficiently ?

Also, is there a a nice way to free memory taken by UIImageView in Swift?

So, to be more precise, view controller's deinit doesn't get called when view controller gets poped from navigation stack. The same applies to some custom subviews of that view controller. How can I ensure that they get cleaned by ARC, and are there any tools that can help me track references that keep these things in memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, so I solved it. The quick tip for everyone who might be having the same problem. 
1)Have all the fields (except numbers and books as optionals). Nil them out in deinit.
2) Nil out everything that can reference your object in memory, a good example, which is easy to forget is delegation. If your view acts like a delegate, don't forget to break this connection.
3)If you are using maps in your apps, it is advisable to use one shared map and redraw  and change its delegate every time, rather then instant instinct new maps on every view with them. Maps can be hard to clean from memory(I tried map applyMemoryFix, it didn't work)

Comment: Thanks, reusing a map did it for me. I was also calling mapView.removeAnnotations(myPolylines) instead of mapView.removeOverlays(myPolylines) which presumably was keeping my map in memory.

Comment: p.s, my deint wasnt being called due to reference cycles, had to nil everything in viewWillDisappear